# Ng-map (angular map) is not working now

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

Previuosly when I use ng-map it was working fine but now its not working, I get blank map. I am getting this error from google map api:

> The Google Maps JavaScript API must be downloaded directly from
>   Google's servers. Learn more:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API

Comment: You did not include google map script properly..

Comment: ya it was due to the offline google map js file

Comment: Tip: I used bower to install this without looking at the github page. Turns out somebody has created an 'ng-maps' bower dependency which is seemingly unrelated to this one. Be sure to use `bower install ngmap` instead of `bower install ng-maps`. (Of course, I would have seen this straight away if I had looked at the github page instead of diving in feet first!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you *should* be downloading the google maps JS from google's servers, as stated in ng-maps' [DOCS](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)

Include Google maps:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Name your angular app ngMap, or add it as a dependency

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']);
```

Comment: thank you , that was a small mistake I was using offline google-map.js file for google map

Comment: Google Maps JavaScript API doesn't support offline mode. Please also note  that according to the documentation you should load API from maps.googleapis.com domain:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en#Loading_the_Maps_API